# Cant store data to related table spring

Tags: java, spring

I have table `employee` and table `employee_detail`, I can add data to non related table(`employee`), controller work fine, everything is okey, but I cant implement code so I can store data to related table `employee_detail`

`Employee:`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "employeeId")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee")
    private EmployeeDetail employeeDetail;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public EmployeeDetail getEmployeeDetail() {
        return employeeDetail;
    }

    public void setEmployeeDetail(EmployeeDetail employeeDetail) {
        this.employeeDetail = employeeDetail;
    }

}
```

`EmployeeDetail:`

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "employee_detail")
    public class EmployeeDetail {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="employee_detail_id")
        private int id;
    
        @Column(name="work_experience")
        private int workExperience;
    
        @Column(name="hobby")
        private String hobby;
    
        @Column(name="nationality")
        private String nationality;
    
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="employeeId")
        private Employee employee;
    
    
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public int getWorkExperience() {
            return workExperience;
        }
    
        public void setWorkExperience(int workExperience) {
            this.workExperience = workExperience;
        }
    
        public String getHobby() {
            return hobby;
        }
    
        public void setHobby(String hobby) {
            this.hobby = hobby;
        }
    
        public String getNationality() {
            return nationality;
        }
    
        public void setNationality(String nationality) {
            this.nationality = nationality;
        }
    
        public Employee getEmployee() {
            return employee;
        }
    
        public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
            this.employee = employee;
        }
    
    
    }
```

This is how I store data to `employee` table:

```
`EmployeeController:`



 @Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listEmployee(Model theModel) {

        // get customers from the service
        List<Employee> theEmployee = employeeService.listEmployee();

        // add the customers to the model
        theModel.addAttribute("employees", theEmployee);

        return "list-employee";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showFormForAdd")
    public String showFormForAdd(Model theModel) {

        // create model attribute to bind form data
        Employee theEmployee = new Employee();

        theModel.addAttribute("employee", theEmployee);

        return "addNewEmployeeForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addNewEmployee")
    public String addNewEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee theEmployee) {

        // save the customer using our service
        employeeService.addNewEmployee(theEmployee);

        return "redirect:/employee/list";
    }

}
```

And form `addNewEmployeeForm:`

```
 <form:form action="addNewEmployee" modelAttribute="employee" method="POST">

    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label>First name:</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Last name:</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Email:</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label></label></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" /></td>
        </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How to store data into table from related table? What m I missing?

I tried like this but doesnt work:

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping("/employeeDetail")
public class EmployeeDetailController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDetailService employeeDetailService;


    @GetMapping("/listEmployeeDetail")
    public String listEmployeeDetail(Model theModel) {

        // get customers from the service
        List<EmployeeDetail> theEmployeeDetail = employeeDetailService.listEmployeeDetail();

        // add the customers to the model
        theModel.addAttribute("employeeDetails", theEmployeeDetail);

        return "list-employeeDetail";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showFormForAddEmployeeDetail")
    public String showFormForAddEmployeeDetail(Model theModel) {

        // create model attribute to bind form data
        EmployeeDetail theEmployeeDetail = new EmployeeDetail();

        theModel.addAttribute("employeeDetail", theEmployeeDetail);

        return "addNewEmployeeDetailForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addNewEmployeeDetail")
    public String addNewEmployeeDetail(@ModelAttribute("employeeDetail") EmployeeDetail theEmployeeDetail) {

        // save the customer using our service
        employeeDetailService.addNewEmployeeDetail(theEmployeeDetail);

        return "redirect:/employeeDetail/listEmployeeDetail";
    }


}
```

Requested code:

```
 @Override
@Transactional
public void addNewEmployeeDetail(EmployeeDetail theEmployeeDetail) {
    employeeDetailDAO.addNewEmployeeDetail(theEmployeeDetail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are not actively saving the `EmployeeDetail` entities on your own and only saving `Employee`, then configure `cascade` attribute on `@OneToOne` relationship on `Employee` side as follows:

```java
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private EmployeeDetail employeeDetail;
```

With this, you are telling your EntityManager to propagate (cascade) all operations (PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH) to the relating entities.

---

In addition to the change above, I would also recommend you moving to JPA instead of handling Hibernate Sessions on your own.

Include the Spring Boot JPA dependency in your pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Create two repositories, one for each entity and inject them into the corresponding Service (just like you are doing with your DAOs):

```java
public interface EmployeeDAO extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
}


public interface EmployeeDetailDAO extends JpaRepository<EmployeeDetail, Integer> {
}
```

Now in your Services, you can call a couple of default methods on these Repositories such as `findAll()` or `save()`. In your case you would do something like the following:

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public void addNewEmployee(Employee theEmployee) {
    employeeDAO.save(theEmployee);
}
```

You can check more details at https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories.

Keep in mind that you will have a hard time saving `EmployeeDetail` directly as you receive it from your form. The reason being that you need to set `Employee` attribute, otherwise the foreign key in the column `employeeId` would be set and thus you will get a SQL error.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my code but still doesnt work. I need implemention for controller I guess so I can save data to related table, in this case `employeeDetail`

Comment: Can you please share the code of the method ´employeeService.addNewEmployee(theEmployee);´? So that we can check how you are persisting the Employee data. Additionally, what do you mean by "it does not work"? Do you see any error or data is simply not persisted?

Comment: No, no errors on GF log, just 404 not found. Im not persisting Employee data, idk how to implement on right way that. I put code on question.

Comment: Github: https://github.com/jankostefan/Employee_Tracking_System1

Comment: Well if there is a 404 HTTP status code, then you may be calling the endpoint in the wrong way. We need the request details then.

Comment: While debugging do you see the code on `listEmployeeDetail()` `EmployeeDetailController` method being called? Do you see anything on the browser or do you simply get 404 and nothing else?

Comment: Just 404 not found, on GF log also nothing

Comment: But you are able to POST `addNewEmployeeDetail` form right? If so while debugging do you see the code on listEmployeeDetail() EmployeeDetailController method being called?

Comment: I don't think we're going anywhere like this, it's not a problem, the problem is the implementation of code to add data to a table that is related to the main table. The implementation of the code must be different because the two entities are connected. Look at class `EmployeeDetailController` it needs to be changed. Also, look at this question, is almost same, and look answers on it, I need something like that, just dont know how to implement it in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806396/add-data-to-database-related-tables-spring-boot

Comment: Also, when I manually run my employee detail list page its work, problem is storing data to table, I need to fix it

Comment: Then I would recommend you moving to JPA instead of handling Hibernate Sessions on your own. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Okey, lets try it then